# Determine if the events $A$ and $B$ are incompatible if $P(A)=\dfrac{2}{5}$ and $P(B)=\dfrac{5}{7}.$

Tags: probability

> Determine if the events $A$ and $B$ are incompatible if
>   $P(A)=\dfrac{2}{5}$ and $P(B)=\dfrac{5}{7}.$

I really don't know how to approach it. To see when two events are compatible or not, we can observe if they have (a) common element(s). Two events are compatible if $A\cap B \neq\emptyset$ and on the contrary, they are incompatible if $A\cap B =\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inclusion-exclusion tells us that $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

Rearranging, we have $P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)$

We have then $P(A\cap B)=\frac{2}{5}+\frac{5}{7}-P(A\cup B)\geq \frac{2}{5}+\frac{5}{7}-1>0$

Thus, $P(A\cap B)>0$ and so $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$

Comment: How did you go from the first line to the second: $P(A \cap B)=...$?

Comment: @thornton.sohan going from the first line to the second line?  I added $P(A\cap B)$ to both sides and then subtracted $P(A\cup B)$ from both sides...

Comment: Isn't the sign $\le$? I mean ($...\le \frac{2}{5}+\frac{5}{7}-1$).

Comment: Also $\frac{2}{5}+\frac{5}{7}-1<0$.

Comment: @thornton.sohan no.  $P(A\cup B)$ is at most $1$ and at least $0$ (*really, at least $5/7$ due to the value of $P(B)$*).  The larger the value is that you subtract by, the less the result will be and we are interested in finding how small $P(A\cap B)$ can possibly be, so we subtract by the largest possible value for $P(A\cup B)$.  As for $\frac{2}{5}+\frac{5}{7}-1$, that is $\frac{14}{35}+\frac{25}{35}-\frac{35}{35}=\frac{4}{35}>0$, not less than zero.